# Highlight which worksheets in Excel 2016 contain a positive value in a specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a set of several hundred identically laid out worksheets but each containing different data. I want to list all of the sheets where, for example cell E532=1 or E532>0. Can this be done? And if so, how? If it helps, I have Kutools installed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA Subprocedure will identify the names of the worksheets in the active workbook that contain a value greater than 0 in cell E532. The names of the worksheets will output to the Immediate window. Additionally, the color of the worksheet tab will be changed to yellow.

```
Sub ListWorksheets()

For Each ws In Worksheets
    TestValue = ws.Range("E532").Value
    If (TestValue > 0) Then
      Debug.Print ws.Name
      ws.Tab.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

In order to create a list of worksheets that meet the criteria, create a new worksheet and run the following macro. A list of the worksheets will be output starting in the cell that is active when the macro is ran.

```
Sub ListWorksheetsAtActiveColumn()

'Defines the row offset of the current cell to list the worksheets
Dim RowNumber As Long

RowNumber = 0

For Each ws In Worksheets
    TestValue = ws.Range("E532").Value
    If (TestValue > 0) Then
      Debug.Print ws.Name
      'Changes the color of the worksheet tab to yellow
      ws.Tab.ColorIndex = 6
      'Creates a list of worksheet names that meet the test starting
      'at the current cell
      ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 0).Value = ws.Name
      RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I got it to work insofar as it highlighted the tabs in yellow, however is there any way to get it to actually list the names of the tabs so I could repeat this process with multiple different cells and not have to sort through hundreds of tabs? Thanks again.

Comment: The name of the worksheets are printed to the Immediate window in the above code. You could also have the list of worksheets printed to a column on another worksheet.

Comment: They aren't printing. I have run it several times and nothing appears in the sheet, just the change in the tab colour.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub LookFor()
    Dim msg As String, addy As String, v As Variant
    Dim w As Worksheet
    msg = ""
    addy = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter cell address", Type:=2)
    v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter cell value", Type:=3)

    For Each w In Worksheets
        If w.Range(addy) = v Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & w.Name
        End If
    Next

    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "nothing found"
    Else
        MsgBox msg
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting close to what I am after but how would you get it to list the addresses in a selectable format so they could be copied and pasted into another document and would it be possible to skip the "enter cell value" step and have it just list all cells with a value greater than zero?